# Kafka has higher throughput in at-least-once mode than at-most-once mode, how can this be?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am experimenting with kafka and comparing at-least-once performance with at-most-once performance. However from my test runs, at-least-once seems to have higher throughput then at-most-once? This makes no sense since at-least-once use acknowledgements etc. Below is the settings i use.

**For at-most-once i use the following settings:**

Producer

```
properties.put("acks", "0");
properties.put("retries", 0);
```

Consumer

```
properties.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
```

**For at-least-once i use the following settings:**

Producer

```
(Standard settings)
```

Consumer

```
properties.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
```

And i do

```
kafkaConsumer.commitSync();
```

After each ConsumerRecords poll

**How the measurements is performed**

In my test-bench i am measuring two values:

1. (Throughput) The amount of messages that is received by the consumer each second
2. (Latency) The average latency for the messages received by the consumer each second

When i am running Kafka in at-most-once mode the latency is higher and the throughput is lower

Comment: You need to explain what you are measuring and how and also share some logic.

Comment: I updated the question, however the logic for the test bench is quite long and complicated.